# Search two patterns in one line in tcl using regex

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string as follows:

```
o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200
```

Now I need to write a code to check whether the string "`o=India-SIPUA`" as well as the string `10.77.33.200` are present in the above string or not.

I wrote the following code:

```
[regexp {.*o=India-SIPUA.*10.77.34.200} $buf match],
```

but it's not working

---

I need to search those 2 from a chunk of codes. I am writing the below one

```
set buffer "v=0
o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200
s=SIP Call"

set patt "o=India-SIPUA"
set ipaddress "10.77.34.200" 
#set port ""

foreach buf [split $buffer "\n"] {
  if {[regexp {.*o=$patt.*$ipaddress} $buf match]} {
     puts "+++++++Port==$match++++++"
     return 1
  } else {
     puts "Problem in getting port.."
     return 0
  }
}
```

But it is always going to the else part and never entering into the if part.

So can you say what's going wrong?

Comment: You have 33 in your string but 34 in the expression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for the value you specify: you have `10.77.33.200` in the string, and `10.77.34.200` in the regex. Also, pay attention to `.`: to match a literal dot, you need to escape it.

Here is a working code that finds both values:

```
set buff "SOME TEXT o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200"
regexp {.*o=India-SIPUA.*10\.77\.33\.200} $buff match
puts $match
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/LRdlTB)

**EDIT**:

To match any 2 digits in Group 3 of the IP, you can use `\d{2}` ([see demo](https://ideone.com/4KKNn5)):

```
set buff "SOME TEXT o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200"
regexp {.*o=India-SIPUA.*(10\.77\.\d{2}\.200)} $buff match ip
puts $match
puts $ip
```

Output:

```
SOME TEXT o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200
10.77.33.200
```

Comment: You can use `\d{2}` instead of `33` to capture 2 digits: `regexp {.*o=India-SIPUA.*10\.77\.\d{2}\.200} $buff match`. Or use just `\d+` to capture 1 or more digits. I have updated the demo and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expression matching for this:

```
set a o=India-SIPUA
set b 10.77.33.200
if { [string first $a $buff] != -1 && [string first $b $buff] != -1 } {
    puts match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that substitutions are *not* performed within braces, so you will have to use quotes and double escape any escapes within the regex:

```
set buffer "v=0
o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200
s=SIP Call"

set patt "India-SIPUA"
# Here we have to raw the string and I changed your pattern
set ipaddress [string map {. \\.} "10.77.33.200"]

foreach buf [split $buffer "\n"] {
  if {[regexp "o=$patt.*\\y$ipaddress\\y" $buf match]} {
     puts "+++++++Port==$match++++++"
  } else {
     puts "Problem in getting port.."
  }
}
```

`stdout` outputs:

```
Problem in getting port..
+++++++Port==o=India-SIPUA 6264 0 IN IP4 10.77.33.200++++++
Problem in getting port..
```

Comment: @Ratnadeep You are welcome. Since you accepted the other answer, does that mean that the other one worked best to solve your problem? I have added word boundaries that I missed earlier because the regexp as is could match a different IP address as well, such as `110.77.33.200`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex:

```
.*?o=India-SIPUA .*?10\.77\.33\.200.*
```

.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

[Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/cE0bT9/1)